# Is there any difference between unity Editor and android on ugui?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I use unity eidtor, I make an UI game object's position down 30, the game object will out of the screen.

But when I build & run this in android, it does not, it just down a bit, far more than out of screen. Is there any difference between them?

```
targetPosition = originPosition + new Vector3(0, -30, 0);
```

The UI ui scale mode is "Scale With Screen Size", and the game window's resolution is 720x1280, just like my android device.

Answer (score 0):

I see, I should use transform.localPosition instead of transform.position.